# Merge check on bitbucket before PR merge

Tags: bitbucket

How to determine checklist for Bitbucket PR on merge pop-up?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/suggest-or-require-checks-before-a-merge-856691474.html):

> Merge checks apply to individual branches or branch patterns along with branch permissions. The rest of this section expands the example we used to describe branch permissions and includes merge checks.

So you need to go to **Settings > Branch permissions** and click on **Add a branch permission**, then use drop down **Merge Checks**. And choose options from below list - like on picture:

[image: Add a branch permission]

Comment: What version is this? I don't seems to have those options at all. Or is this pluging related ? We seems to be on Atlassian Bitbucket v6.10.3 at work.

Comment: @ForceMagic I think I using standard Bitbucket Cloud version from https://bitbucket.org